# The import org.eclipse cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, import

I cloned a git java project with Eclipse, but I get many errors because I cant resolve these imports:

```
import org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
```

What should I do?

I use Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Version: Mars Release (4.5.0).

Solution:
The source was an eclipse plugin, and I needed JAVA EE Eclipse to compile and run it. Thanks for the help greg-449.

Comment: Try cleaning your project. If it doesn't work, restart Eclipse and do again.

Comment: It's still not working. Should I download these from somewhere?

Comment: What you have is an Eclipse plugin project. How did you create this project?

Comment: Right click -> Import -> Project from Git -> Clone URI -> Import existing Eclipse projects

Comment: So what do the MANIFEST.MF and plugin.xml files contain?

Comment: updated the question, the plugin xml file has 200 rows, what to look for?

Comment: I'm not sure that 'Eclipse IDE for Java Developers' contains the Plugin Development Environment code. In the Preferences dialog do you have a 'Plug-in Development' entry?

Comment: No, i dont have it. What version should I use?

Comment: You can install it using 'Help > Install New Software', work with the main Mars site and install 'Eclipse Plugin Development Environment'. Note that the code you are trying to build is an Eclipse plugin and will only run as part of Eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers does not contain the Eclipse Plugin Development Environment needed to build and run this project.

You can install it using 'Help > Install New Software'. Work with the main site for your version of Eclipse (Mars in your case) and install 'Eclipse Plugin Development Environment'.

Note that the code you are trying to build is an Eclipse plugin and will only run as part of Eclipse.