# The import org.eclipse cannot be resolved...how to install Eclipse Plugin Development Environment?

Tags: java, eclipse, import

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650103/the-import-org-eclipse-cannot-be-resolved) I'm supposed to "install it using 'Help > Install New Software'. Work with the main Mars site and install 'Eclipse Plugin Development Environment'"

Is help the same bar as in the Eclispe software? 
[image]

When I google "'Eclipse Plugin Development Environment" I click this [link](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/). Then I click download > 4.6.1 > [eclipse-SDK-4.6.1-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.6.1-201609071200/). But that just gives me a new Eclipse. What I really want is for this library (org.eclipse) to work:
[image]

If someone could provide me step by step instructions on how to fix my Eclipse so that org.eclipse works correctly that would be great!

**Eclipse info**
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)
Build id: 20161007-1200

Comment: > Is help the same bar as in the Eclispe software?


YES! Especially if you see an "Install new Software" option there.

Comment: Help is the 'Help' in the menu bar at the very top. If you have Neon you work with the Neon site rather than Mars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Eclipse Neon click the 'Help' menu item and select 'Install New Software...'.

In the 'Work with' field in the dialog that appears select the Neon site `Neon - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon`.

After a few moments the dialog should update to show something like:

[image]

Expand the 'General Purpose Tools' section and select 'Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment':
[image]

Click Next to proceed with the install.

Once installed you will need to add the appropriate plug-in to your plug-in's dependencies